# Intel XEON 9th generation on socket LGA 1151 ("H4") and Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, intel, xeon, chipset

I'm about to buy a `INTEL Xeon E-2246G` (if I'm lucky to get one here) and put it into `MSI MB Sc LGA1151 Z370-A PRO` (https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z370-A-PRO) and I have two uncertainties:

1. Does "1151" socket stating "*supports 9th gen Intel...*" also include XEON CPUs? I believe it does, I am just not sure and unable to find out. I used to think XEONs need special sockets...
2. Anyone has got experience running modern motherboards like the one above on Windows Server 2012 R2? I am not sure if this OS is officially supported or not, because it is not stated here https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/125903

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it does not, **XEON E-22XX needs special socket: C246** [[source]](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191043/intel-xeon-e-2246g-processor-12m-cache-3-60-ghz.html?wapkw=xeon%202246g#tab-blade-1-1-0)
2. There are no official drivers at all on Intel page (by 2019-08-07) [[source]](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/147326/intel-c246-chipset) However, LAN drivers are available by some manufacturers, e.g. ASUS [[source]](https://www.asus.com/us/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/WS-C246-PRO/HelpDesk_Download/)